# Wacom Intus tablet is panning instead of painting

Tags: settings, tablet, wacom

I've been trying to find some info on how to fix this, but I'm clearly typing the wrong stuff into google.

Basically imagine you have canvas in Photoshop.
You press the brush tool to paint a horizontal red line with your Wacom pen.
But instead of painting a red horizontal line, the screen pans to the right.

No red line, just moved the slider over to see the right of the screen.
I don't want that. I want to paint. I don't want to move the slider.

Also - every time I hold down the pen, a little dialog pops up that lets me change the brush settings. I don't want that either. If I hold the pen harder on the tablet, I'm trying to push down to make the stroke thicker. But instead of a thicker stroke, I get brush settings.

WTF Wacom?

Answer (score 1):

Last Windows update caused this. Here's how to fix this: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2398372